# ValueEventListener never being entered

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ValueEventListener, and the inner code is never being reached. My app is authenticating, but I can't retrieve data and I'm not sure what I'm missing. In the code below, when I check, uid has the correct value, and the data path ("Users/[uid]") is correct, but none of the inner code in the value event listener is never being reached. I've also tried to place a listener right at the root, with the same result.

I've set up Firebase using the menu options, adding both Authentication and Realtime Database to my app; authentication is working fine, so I'm wondering if there is something else that needs to be configured for the realtime database? I've read the documentation and walked through many examples but I can't see anything I'm missing.

```
uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
    DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).getRef();

    ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            if (user == null) {
                SettingsLoad();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("User", "User not found" );
        }
    };

    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);
```

Comment: Please don't call `.getRef()` after `child()`. It's unneeded and will cause problems at some point (though it's not the cause of your current problem). Just: `DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
I've just added else condition and log or toast the results!!

```
uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().toString();
        DatabaseReference userRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).getRef();

    ValueEventListener userListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            if (user == null) {
                SettingsLoad();
            }
**else {
Log.d("tag","User Found!");
}**
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("User", "User not found" );
        }
    };

    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userListener);
```